# Trouble Achieving Desired Layout for Chat Messages in the page

Tags: html, css, layout, web-applications

I'm currently working on a chat interface and I'm facing an issue with displaying the chat messages. Currently, the chat messages are appearing in a single line as shown in this image:

[The screenshot of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu42R.png)

However, I want each message to be displayed in a separate line as shown in this image:

[The screenshot of what layout i wanted in my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmBV6.png)

I have tried adding
`display: block`
to the .chtmsg-content class and adjusting the adjusting the CSS properties for the chat messages CSS properties for the chat messages but it didn't work.

The HTML code I'm using for my page:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chat-container">
      <div class="chthdr">
        <h3>Chatkura</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="chtbd">
        <div class="chtmsg">
          <div class="chtmsg-content">Hello! How can I help you today
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="cht-tis">
            <img class="usrpn" src="R.png" alt="user icon"> <div class="chtusr">
              <span class="msgsp">hello</span>
          </div>
          <img class="usrpn" src="R.png" alt="user icon"> <div class="chtusr">
            <span class="msgsp">hello</span>
        </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="cht-btreps">
            <img src="bot.png" alt="bot icon"> <div class="chtmsg-reps">
              <span class="msgsp">hi</span>
              </div>
              <img src="bot.png" alt="bot icon"> <div class="chtmsg-reps">
                <span class="msgsp">hi</span>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.chat-container {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #1f7c22;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 20px 38px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: 60%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 15px auto;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .chthdr {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #36bbb033;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
  }
  
  .chtbd {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 30vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  
  .chtmsg{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .usrpn{
    width: 27px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  }
  img{
    width: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    height: fit-content;
  }
  .chturs{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .chtmsg-content {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: max-content;
    padding: 11px;
    box-shadow: 10px 4px 31px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .cht-tis{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
  }

  .msgsp{
    font-size: 18px;
    max-width: 50%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  .chtusr{
    background-color: #23a875;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: 10px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    max-width: 70%;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }

  .cht-btreps{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
  }

  .chtmsg-reps{
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #c2c2c2;
    border-radius: 9px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 75%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
THANKS IN ADVANCE !! and THANK YOU FOR READING

Answer (score 0):

There were some divs that were missing closing tags and some of them have the closing tags outside their own scope.

So I've rearranged your HTML, hope this is what you wanted.

```
<div class="chat-container">
    <div class="chthdr">
      <h3>Chatkura</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="chtbd">
      <div class="chtmsg">
        <div class="chtmsg-content">Hello! How can I help you today
        </div>
        <div class="cht-tis">
          <img class="usrpn" src="R.png" alt="user icon">
          <div class="chtusr">
            <span class="msgsp">hello</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cht-tis">
          <img class="usrpn" src="R.png" alt="user icon">
          <div class="chtusr">
            <span class="msgsp">hello</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cht_bot_wraper">
        <div class="cht-btreps">
          <img src="bot.png" alt="bot icon">
          <div class="chtmsg-reps">
            <span class="msgsp">hi</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cht-btreps">
          <img src="bot.png" alt="bot icon">
          <div class="chtmsg-reps">
            <span class="msgsp">hi</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>




    </div>
  </div>
```